# Custom Input Field on Checkout Page in Opencart:3

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3, journal

I want to have a Custom Input field under **Payment Method**, to get GST Tax detail before placing Order. And I am Using Journal 3 Theme. which has a One-Page checkout.

So, i have tried this article:- https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=172521

At catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/journal3/checkout/payment_method.twig ---added this line

```
<input name="get_gst" type="text" placeholder="{{ custom_gst }}" class="form-control">
```

At catalog/controller/checkout/payment_method.php

```
$this->session->data['comment'] = strip_tags($this->request->post['comment']);      //Under this line
$this->session->data['your_field'] = strip_tags($this->request->post['get_gst']);   //I added this line
```

At catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php

```
$order_data['comment'] = $this->session->data['comment'];    //Under this line
$order_data['get_gst'] = $this->session->data['get_gst'];    //I added this line
```

At catalog/model/checkout/order.php

```
, comment = '" . $this->db->escape($data['comment']) . "'    //after this line
, get_gst = '" . $this->db->escape($data['get_gst']) . "'    //I added this line
```

**And After All** getting this errro...

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
OK

I have noticed a difference that this theme is getting other field data(Like: Comment box) by **v-model="order_data.comment"** as shown below, rather than name attribute like i used.

```
<textarea class="form-control" v-model="order_data.comment" placeholder="{{ text_comments }}"></textarea>
```

So, i also tried this **v-model="get_gst"** in my input, but then i am getting an empty checkout page.

Anyone know where is Getting ERROR? Thank You in Advance.

[Checkout js file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10cO9CpvDGwLZ-7RP4thqhxpGqxOrU77G)

Comment: Any help will be Appreciated !

Comment: Also, i tried this in simple opencart But error is same: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ease solution - you take any field from payment address, which is currently unused (like Address 2), change it's title to "GST Tax detail" in opencart language files catalog/language/en-gb/checkout/checkout.php.

Address list from Account & Address list under billing details of checkout, Both are taking their data from catalog/controller/accout/address.php in protected function getList(). So, we only need to modify checkout/payment_address.tpl file. Just add

```
<?php echo $address['address_2']; ?>
```

AFTER

```
<?php echo $address['address_1']; ?>
```

We need to add this because OpenCart only show Address 1 field in Payment method & Billing details section on Checkout page. So, by this we can show Address 2 field on it.

Comment: Okay, Also I apply these changes on both Journal 3 & simple theme 2.3.0.2, And i got Same error that i mentioned above. But this new article solved my issue (https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=204399) on opencart 2.3.0.2 only. Because i can not find and change the json script code on Journal theme. MEANS, we only need to apply this new article changes on journal theme. I attached the checkout js file at the END, maybe where we need to do changes, have a look on question...

Comment: Still not working. Maybe because - Payment method is only sending the radio button data and we need to include input field in script, Like they told here: https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=204399

Comment: And if we go with your First plan to change Address 2 field change to GST. Then there is one thing need to change::-- As we know that opencart only show Address 1 Field in Payment method & Billing details Section on checkout page. So, how can i modify it so it also show address 2 field also(which i had changes to GST).

Comment: If we are talking about journal 3 checkout page - Than go to Admin - Journal - Skins - Default (or any you currently use) - Checkout. On the bottom of page find Fields - Address - and Ardess 2 visibility settings.

Comment: If we using simple opencart 2.3.0.2. ? Any Suggestion...?

Comment: Think, in simple settings there is although some extra field settings. Can't go any farther with the answer because the lack of modules description. Links on simple demo or your site demo are welcome.

Comment: Thank You, You got me Answer::-- Address list from Account & Address list under billing details of checkout, Both are taking their data from catalog/controller/accout/address.php in protected function getList().   So, we only need to modify checkout/payment_address.tpl file --> Just add , <?php echo $address['address_2']; ?> AFTER , <?php echo $address['address_1']; ?>

Comment: You can Update your Answer, and i will Mark it GREEN. And Thank You Again.

Comment: Also add a line that we need to add this bcoz opencart only show Address 1 Field in Payment method & Billing details Section on checkout page. So, by this we can show Address 2 field on it. This will help other...

Answer (score 2):

Seems you not properly add to the session your field.

At catalog/controller/checkout/payment_method.php

This line incorrect:

```
$this->session->data['your_field'] = strip_tags($this->request->post['get_gst']);   //I added this line
```

Should be:

```
$this->session->data['get_gst'] = strip_tags($this->request->post['get_gst']);   //I added this line
```

Journal 3 them looks great from the first sight... But I do not recommend to use Journal 3 theme. This theme very complicated and ruining OC framework.